# What's the reason of "FimgApiStretch:stretch failed" in Android

Tags: android

In logcat, it always log out "FimgApiStretch:stretch failed".
It appears especially when I am using listview.
But it never crash or force close.
Anyone knows what the reasons?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This seems to just be some form of logging on Samsung devices. Samsung are quite known for making a mess in android LogCat with system messages.

I've seen the issue constantly on my Galaxy S3 with stock Touchwiz ROM, but it has never been linked to any issue.

Don't worry about it and just bear with the mess.

Comment: I can confirm that problem as my S3 with original Software does the same.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same "Issue" get this message. 
I have seen when trying to use the [Widget Switch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html)

This widget was not customizable on `S3 texton` or `textoff` (working fine with a S2) or using AVD.

My understanding of the issue, is that the widget (listview in your case or Switch in my case) is working partially...